# How To multiple Euro values total arrays in ios Swift 5 Like ["£179.95", "£199.95", "£89.95"]

Tags: ios, swift4, cart

array = ["£179.95", "£199.95", "£89.95"]

How to multiple this values add get the total values in ios swift 4.

Please help me.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. I think you should elaborate a little more what exactly you want to do and what is your problem. Are you struggling to parse the strings in your array (British Pounds btw, not EUR)? Or is it something else? It's best to include the code that you have written so far and explain where you're experiencing problems. That way it's most likely to find help quickly. Also see here: [ask]

Comment: What is the input, what is the expected output (and according to what rules), what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure that the strings contained in your array always start with a `£`, you could do this:

```
let sum = array.compactMap { Double($0.replacingOccurrences(of: "£", with: "")) }
               .reduce(0.0, { $0 + $1 })
```

Example:

```
let array = ["£179.95", "£199.95", "£89.95"]
let sum = array.compactMap { Double($0.replacingOccurrences(of: "£", with: "")) }
               .reduce(0.0, { $0 + $1 })
print(sum) // 469.84999999999997
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a flexible solution by using a `NumberFormatter`

```
var formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

and then calculate the sum by setting the proper currency code

```
formatter.currencyCode = "GBP"
let sum = array.compactMap { formatter.number(from: $0)?.doubleValue}.reduce(0.0, +)
```

So just change the `currencyCode` property as needed or use the `currencySymbol` property instead

```
let euroValues = ["€10.4", "€5.67"]
formatter.currencySymbol = "€"
let euroSum = euroValues.compactMap { formatter.number(from: $0)?.doubleValue}.reduce(0.0, +)
```