# How to Multiple Two String Arrays and get total value in ios swift 4

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4

I have Two arrays like below i a want calculate 2 array values and get total value according to qty. 
["1", "1"]
["£129.95", "£129.95"]

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried?  You will need to iterate over the array indices, parse the strings to aNot Int and a decimal number and then perform the multiplication.

Comment: For reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41884630/swift-convert-currency-string-to-double

Comment: Since you have already asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59067075/how-to-multiple-euro-values-total-arrays-in-ios-swift-5-like-£179-95-£199-9) I assume you have some code you have tried and can share.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to add/multiple numbers in both array. And not sure what do you want to calculate from two arrays. So I've added example code below to add and multiple two string arrays.

```
func calculateTwoArrays(){

        let array1 = ["1", "1"]
        let array2 = ["£129.95", "£129.95"]

        //Add all values together
        var total:Double = 0.0

        for value in array1 {

            if let number = Double(value.replacingOccurrences(of: "£", with: "")){

                total += number
            }
        }

        print("Total:\(total)")

        //Multiply array values, assuming array1 as quantity and array 2 as price.
        var priceArray = [Double]()

        for quantity in array1 {

            for price in array2 {

                if let quantityValue = Double(quantity), let priceValue = Double(price.replacingOccurrences(of: "£", with: "")){

                    priceArray.append(quantityValue*priceValue)
                }
            }
        }

        total = priceArray.reduce(0, +)

        print("Total:\(total)")
}
```

Comment: I want calculate array 1 index 0 to array 2 , array 1 index 1 to array 2 index 1 and final total like cart value

Comment: do you want to multiply and add like (array1-index-0 * array2-index-0and1) + (array1-index-1 with array2-index-0and1)?